# Get app name from bundle id

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have list with bundle id`s from apps that are installed on device and i want to get the app names. Solution should work on not jail broken devices. The app would not go on app store so the app rejection doesn't metter.

---

I found this solution, which will return detailed info for app if it is located on app store. 
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.bundle.id

Answer (score 28):

Most of the time, you can get with this...

```
NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(id)kCFBundleNameKey];
```

EDIT:

AS you want to find for all the apps.

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"BundleIdentifier"] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(id)kCFBundleExecutableKey];
NSLog(@"AppName: %@",appName);
```

Comment: Yes but this solotion is only for current application.

Comment: you want for all the applications?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to discover all installed apps on device, i figured out how to find bundle is`s, so i needed display name.

Comment: see the Edit: for all apps

Comment: Note that `CFBundleDisplayName` is the actual human-friendly name of the application that is displayed on the home screen, etc.

Comment: There is a key for that: kCFBundleNameKey. No need to hardcode keys.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya...Can we get appId from bundle id.Suppose I have all the bundle id of installed apps and I want app id for all or if possible app icon for all either using bundle id or app name which ever is possible.

Comment: @Imran: I think its not possible.

Answer (score 11):

This should do it.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"yourBundleIdentifier"];
NSString *appName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
```

---

### Method

```
- (NSString *)titleOfAppWithBundleIdentifier:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:bundleIdentifier];
    return [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I set up the bundle dictionary as follows:

```
NSDictionary *bundleInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

NSString *appName = [bundleInfo objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

And here is the `bundleInfo` dumped:

```
{
    BuildMachineOSBuild = ...;
    CFBundleDevelopmentRegion = ...;
    CFBundleDisplayName = ...;
    CFBundleExecutable = ...;
    CFBundleIcons = {
        CFBundlePrimaryIcon = {
        CFBundleIconFiles = (
            "AppIcon29x29.png",
            "AppIcon29x29@2x.png",
            "AppIcon40x40@2x.png",
            "AppIcon57x57.png",
            "AppIcon57x57@2x.png",
            "AppIcon60x60@2x.png",
            "AppIcon60x60@3x.png"
        );
        UIPrerenderedIcon = 1;
       };
    };
    CFBundleIdentifier = ...;
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = ...;
    CFBundleInfoPlistURL = ...;
    CFBundleName = ...;
    CFBundleNumericVersion = 0;
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = ...;
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
        iPhoneOS
    );
    CFBundleVersion = "1.0.11";
    DTCompiler = ...;
    DTPlatformBuild = ...;
    DTPlatformName = iphoneos;
    DTPlatformVersion = "8.3";
    DTSDKBuild = ...;
    DTSDKName = "iphoneos8.3";
    DTXcode = ...;
    DTXcodeBuild = ...;
    LSRequiresIPhoneOS = 1;
    MinimumOSVersion = "5.1";
    UIBackgroundModes =     (
        ...,
        ...
    );
    UIDeviceFamily =     (
        1
    );
    UILaunchImageFile = LaunchImage;
    UILaunchImages =     (
            {
            UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion = "7.0";
            UILaunchImageName = ...;
            UILaunchImageOrientation = Portrait;
            UILaunchImageSize = "{320, 568}";
        }
    );
    UIMainStoryboardFile = Main;
    UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities =     (
        armv7
    );
    UISupportedInterfaceOrientations =     (
        UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
    );
    UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is returning nil for me

Comment: This is working fine for me. Just a typo in your syntax:
NSDictionary *bundleInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get localized bundle display name, use `localizedInfoDictionary`:

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedInfoDictionary][@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should give you the answer:

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"BundleIdentifier"] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
if let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.my.bundleId"),
    let name = bundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String) {
    print(name)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
NSString *appName = [[bundleID componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];
```

Assuming that the bundleIDs are in reverse dns format..

Comment: This isn't really smart, because the BundleID can be completely different.

Comment: Not to mention contains no spaces or special characters.