# OpenURL - many apps try to open App 'A'. Find the source that opened App A

Tags: ios, swift, openurl, info-plist

I am using `OpenURL` from many apps to Open App A. I would like to know the source app that Opened app A. Is there a way to find it?

Say, I have the following apps opening the app `Messenger` using the code

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "messenger://receiveMedia")!)`

- Photos (Through which i can share images)
- WhatsApp (Through which i can share text or Images)
- Instagram

Now i want to figure out which of the apps mentioned above has opened `Messenger`. Is there a way to differentiate the source?

Comment: When `application:openURL:options:` is called its `options` dicitionary will contain `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey` key which will have source application bundle value. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Kind of. I want to know the name of the app than the bundle

Comment: Maybe solutions from here can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023618/get-app-name-from-bundle-id
The link in the question is a sure thing, if you are ok with asking the server for the name.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response Losiowaty.. Its still not working. `let appName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?[sourceApplication!] as? String` is giving only nil and not giving the name.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. Some of the answers actually misunderstood the OP there. You should look at ones with `bundleWithIdentifier` - for example, second code snippet here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14023717/765298. Nevertheless it still seems that querying http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.bundle.id as mentioned in the question would be your best option.